# Вопрос о чередовании а/о в начале матерного выражения

Tags: словообразование, морфология, обсценная-лексика, фонология

Есть выражение "охуеть". Оно соответствует типичной конструкции, когда мы прибавляем "о" в начало слова, чтобы обозначить то, что нечто приобретает какие-то качества или состояния, связанные с тем, что идёт после "о": опасть, опростоволоситься, ослепнуть.
Но внезапно слово "охуеть" трансформируется  выражение "в ахуе". Есть ли языковые нормы или похожие примеры, когда ещё это происходит? Почему не "в охуе"?